# SwaggerResponse attribute when using HttpStatusCode.OK, does not display in UI

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have an asp.net WebAPI REST service where I have incorporated Swashbuckle. I am using the `SwaggerResponse` so that I get it in the UI.

eg on top of my controller method I have

```
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success", typeof(MyModel))]
```

I have the following versions..

```
 <package id="Swashbuckle" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net47" />
 <package id="Swashbuckle.Core" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net47"
```

For example, if I use `HttpStatusCode.Created`, or any status code apart from `HttpStatusCode.OK` it works fine...

[image]

However, as soon as I use the `HttpStatusCode.OK` it just does not show up.

Why does it not appear just for the `HttpStatusCode.OK`?

### Edit 1

The response is in the definition file created, just does not show in the UI. I.e. I have:

```
"responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Success",
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/ClientResultsCollectionModel[ResultsModel]"
        }
      },
      "400": {
        "description": "Invalid input data",
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/ErrorResponseModel"
        }
      },
      "500": {
        "description": "Internal Error",
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/ErrorResponseModel"
        }
      }
```

but only the 400 and 500 show in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my problem was I had css to hide the response that is displayed at the top of the document. I had this as it was often shown empty, but that was before I started adding the `SwaggerResponse` attributes.

It still showed up empty at the top for POSTS, but adding a `[SwaggerResponseRemoveDefaults]` fixed this.

So, for the **GETS** seems to want to put the `200` at the top, separate to the responses in the bottom section.